# Pass value to modal and display as plain text

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, modal-dialog

I have the following which will display a modal when a node in a graph similar to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063550/) is clicked:

Code to make node clickable:

```
var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
        .on("click", function(d){
            $("#modalBody").val(d.relativePath);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
         })
```

Code to display modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" name="modalBody" id="modalBody" value=""/>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can pass a value to the modal to display (`$("#modalBody").val(d.relativePath);`) in the body but it comes up in an edit box (`<input type="text" name="modalBody" id="modalBody" value=""/>`).

Is there anyway to display it as plain text? e.g Display it in a `<p>` tag or something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to use .append() (source here: http://api.jquery.com/append/) or .add() (source: http://api.jquery.com/add/) to append the p element to the dialog box?

Comment: Hey - this works! You should post it as an answer, one question - if I click a few nodes, more and more text is written to the modal. Is there a way to clear the element or overwrite it?

Comment: Just got it, use the `.empty()` method on the element before appending. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.append()` (source here: [api.jquery.com/append](http://api.jquery.com/append)) or `.add()` (source: [api.jquery.com/add](http://api.jquery.com/add)) to append the p element to the dialog box